# CMakeLists.txt Error. - "add_subdirectory(source) - given source "source" which is not an existing directory". I am new to CMake struggling with this

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

This is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project (hello DESCRIPTION "HELLO WORLD" VERSION 20.05.05)

option (TARGET_ONE "Build for Target One" OFF)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set (CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

if (TARGET_ONE)
    add_definitions (-DTARGETONE)
endif()

add_subdirectory (source)
```

EDIT: This is the command I am using:

```
cd ~/build
CMAKE_FLAGS="CXX -DTARGET_ONE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" cmake .
~/build cmake --build .
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the CMake command you are using to your question?

Comment: cd ~/build

CMAKE_FLAGS="CXX -DTARGET_ONE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"

cmake . ~/build

cmake --build .

Comment: Is the `CMakeLists.txt` file you posted the one reciding in the directory shown in the file browser in the screenshot? `add_subdirectory` looks for the subdirectory relative to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the command. You've got 4(!) different `CMakeLists.txt` files open in gedit.

Comment: Hi @fabian yes the CMakeLists.txt file I posted is the one in the file browser in the screenshot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you are calling CMake for the wrong directory.

Given a project directory `<project_dir>` that contains your `CMakeLists.txt` and a subdirectory `source` you can call CMake  as follows:

```
cmake -S <project_dir> -B <build_dir> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DTARGET_ONE=ON
cmake --build <build_dir> --target all --config Release
```

CMake will create the directory `<build_dir>` if it does not exist.

Languages `CXX` and `C` are activated by default if no `LANGUAGES` argument is used in the `project` command.

If your CMake version is less than 3.13 it does not understand the `-S` option and has a different usage of the `-B` option. But it has undocumented  options `-H` and `-B`.
The call then looks like this (no space after `-H` and `-B` options!):

```
cmake -H<project_dir> -B<build_dir> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DTARGET_ONE=ON
```

Comment: The directory cmake is called from is completely irrelevant to the problem. `add_subdirectory` using a relative path always resolves the path relative to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file that contains this `add_subdirectory` command, regardless of whether it's the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` or not. The working directory cmake is called from doesn't matter either.

Comment: @fabian You are right, the directory does not matter. I will reformulate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your .gitmodules file? This file contains submodule path and url. Make sure these are correct.

Answer (score 0):

it's seems when the runner folder is not exist on the fluttter_project/windows directory.
I have solved this problem by copy the runner folder from another flutter project.